# C# - Create tree like structure based on depth values and list indexes

Tags: c#, list, treeview, children

I'm trying to create a tree-like structure. Every class has a parent field and list of children, that is the same class as the parent class. Basic stuff.

Here's a basic version of the class I'm using.

```
public class TreeElement {
    public string name;
    public int depth;
    public int id;

    public TreeElement parent;
    public List<TreeElement> children = new List<TreeElement>();
}
```

Now, when I get the initial data, I get all of these classes in a list. Every item in my tree view is in one big list, and all I can go on is the depth value and the index of the item in the list. So the list would basically look something like this:

```
(0) -1
(1)  |- 0
(2)     |-- 1
(3)     |-- 1
(4)     |   |-- 2
(5)     |-- 1
```

*(x) means the index in the list. The rest of the numbers are the depth values.*

Now to my actual problem. I am having a really hard time making my own list based on these values and I've basically only gotten to where a single item in every child gets added and the siblings get ignored. I really can't find a way to take those into account.

Here's my code so far (which is probably horribly wrong for this):

```
private List<TreeElement> GenerateTreeStructure(List<TreeElement> baseList)
{
    // Base list is the list I get provided with.
    List<TreeElement> newList = new List<TreeElement>();
    TreeElement root = null;
    TreeElement previousFolder = null;
    int previousdepth = -99;

    for (int i = 0; i < baseList.Count; i++)
    {
        TreeElement currentResource = baseList[i];
        if (currentResource.depth == -1 && ShowRootFolder) // The root folder.
        {
            root = currentResource;
            // (Name, depth, parent)
            newList.Add(new TreeElement("Root", currentResource.depth, null));
            previousFolder = root;
            previousdepth = root.depth;
        }
        else if (!ShowRootFolder && currentResource.depth <= 0)
        {
            // If root folder is not shown, take all the children of the root folder instead.
            if (currentResource.depth != -1)
            {
                previousFolder = new TreeElement(currentResource.name, currentResource.depth, null);
                previousdepth = previousFolder.depth;
                newList.Add(previousFolder);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (currentResource.depth > previousdepth)
            {
                TreeElement newResource = new TreeElement(currentResource.name, currentResource.depth, null);
                previousFolder.children.Add(newResource);
                previousdepth = currentResource.depth;
                previousFolder = newResource;
            }
        }
    }

    return newList;
}
```

I hope that explains my problem. I've been stuck with this for quite a while and I hope to get some help with this!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit puzzling why you are returning a list of TreeElement from that GenerateTreeStructure function? You are making a tree structure right? You should be returning just the rootnode? Anyhow, this takes a list with depth values and makes a tree out of it:

```
public static TreeElement GenerateTreeStructure(List<TreeElement> baseList)
{
    TreeElement root = null;
    if (baseList == null || baseList.Count == 0) return root;

    int baseIdx = -1;

    TreeElement prevNode = null;
    TreeElement parent = null;

    while (baseIdx < baseList.Count - 1)
    {
        baseIdx++;
        TreeElement item = baseList[baseIdx];

        if (item.depth == -1)
        {
            root = new TreeElement("root", -1, null);
            prevNode = root;
            continue;
        }

        if (item.depth == prevNode.depth) parent = prevNode.parent; // same level as prevNode
        else if (item.depth > prevNode.depth) parent = prevNode;    // deeper
        else                                                        // shallower
        {
            parent = prevNode.parent;
            while (parent.depth >= item.depth) parent = parent.parent;
        }

        TreeElement newNode = new TreeElement(item.name, item.depth, parent);
        parent.children.Add(newNode);
        prevNode = newNode;
    }

    return root;
}

// to test
void Traverse(TreeElement branch, int depth)
{
    log(new string('\t', depth) + branch.name);
    foreach (var subBranch in branch.children) Traverse(subBranch, depth+1);
}

Traverse(root, 0);
```

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted, thanks a ton! And to clarify why I had it return a list: I need to input a list to the tree view display. But I simply converted it to return a list using your code.

Answer (score 1):

I`ve found two mistakes in logic. Here is fixed code:

```
  // Base list is the list I get provided with.
        List<TreeElement> newList = new List<TreeElement>();
        TreeElement root = null;
        TreeElement previousFolder = null;
        int previousdepth = -99;

        for (int i = 0; i < baseList.Count; i++)
        {
            TreeElement currentResource = baseList[i];
            if (currentResource.depth == -1 && ShowRootFolder) // The root folder.
            {
                root = new TreeElement("Root", currentResource.depth, null);
                // (Name, depth, parent)
                newList.Add(root);
                previousFolder = root;
                previousdepth = root.depth;
            }
            else if (!ShowRootFolder && currentResource.depth <= 0)
            {
                // If root folder is not shown, take all the children of the root folder instead.
                if (currentResource.depth != -1)
                {
                    previousFolder = new TreeElement(currentResource.name, currentResource.depth, null);
                    previousdepth = previousFolder.depth;
                    newList.Add(previousFolder);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (currentResource.depth > previousdepth)
                {
                    TreeElement newResource = new TreeElement(currentResource.name, currentResource.depth, previousFolder);
                    previousFolder.children.Add(newResource);
                    previousdepth = currentResource.depth;
                    previousFolder = newResource;
                }
            }
        }

        return newList;
```

In first "if" statement you created new Root but did not assign it to root object and therefore did not assign it to previousFolder object, which you use in last "if" statement. Also you did not pass previousFolder  object to constructor of TreeElement in last if statement and it would cause problems if you tried go to root element from the bottom using parent field.

P.S. Code is very strange and it seems like you are just starting to learn. If we are talking about tree structure, I would suggest to read about [Composite pattern](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/designpatterns/composite-design-pattern-dotnet) to create a tree in couple with [Visitor pattern](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/designpatterns/visitor-design-pattern-c-sharp) to 'visit' it.

Comment: Thanks for the fixes. It was something I overlooked and missed to fix after I did some tests. And regarding the "strange code", it's probably because this is the first time I'm creating a tree view in these conditions and I'm just testing stuff now. And for 'this', yes, I'm learning, but I'll assure you I do have a few years of C# experience, and I know how to create a tree view... if I know what all the classes are and they are given to me in a reasonable manner. And to be honest, those links you provided didn't help much, but I still appreciate them! They are some interesting reads!